# selecting uitableview cell from "up/down" button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have  a UITableView that I want to scroll down and up without touching it ..

I used this code to change the selected cell

```
-(IBAction)downOrUp:(id)sender{
 NSIndexPath*  Index =[tableViewNames indexPathForSelectedRow]; 

Index =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:Index.row+1 inSection:0];

[tableViewNames selectRowAtIndexPath:Index     animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
 }
```

and this well select the next cell and it works just fine ,,,

in my app when I select a cell some text filed would be filled by the text in the cell.!!

Well, when I click "downOrup" button that text field won't change and remain the same ...

it look that its not calling the didSelectRowAtInAtIndexPath  function!!

Any Ideas!!!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing: are you saying the down or up buttons are disabled if you are editing text within a table view cell?

Comment: the text is out the uitableview totally ,, !!
thnx a lot I got the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didSelectRowAtInAtIndexPath` is called when a user is tapping on a cell. You have to implement what you have already implemented in your `didSelectRowAtInAtIndexPath` but this time in the downOrup function because as you mentioned, when you use `selectRowAtIndexPath`, the user doesn't tap on a cell so `didSelectRowAtInAtIndexPath` is not called.

Comment: yeah exactly ...that what I want . I dunno how did I miss it :)
Thnx a lot Yann :)